# Disruptor with 2 producers, where each feeds a different dependency sub-graph?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, circular-buffer, disruptor-pattern

I'm trying to figure out if Disruptor suits my application: a reasonably complex load generator, used to benchmark high performance databases for long periods of time. The Disruptor pattern is appealing because:

- High throughput
- Low latency
- No garbage / predictable long running behavior

A simplified version of the application topology is as follows:

> ```
>           C1a
>           C1b  
>  P1 ----> C1c 
>           C1d \
>           C1e  \
>                 \
>                  \   
>                   \    
>                    \ 
>                     \ 
>                      \
>                       Cx
>                      /
>  P2 --> C2a --> C2b /
> ```

**=== P1 ===**

The system component fed by `P1` has 1 producer feeding many, parallel consumers (currently an `Executor`). Each event should be processed exactly once, by one of these consumers. The ordering constraint is: if A is produced before B then A will start to execute before B, however B may complete first.

After an event is processed it is forwarded to the final stage, `Cx`. Think of `Cx` as a reducer/logger: it must process events sequentially as the data structures it works on are not thread-safe.

**Question 1: What is the best way of using the Disruptor for processing `C1a-C1e`?**

Using a `WorkerPool` is what I'm leaning towards.

**=== P2 ===**

The system component fed by `P2` is a simple workflow chain: an event is produced by `P2`, `C2a` performs some computation on it, `C2b` performs further computation on it, finally it is forwarded to `Cx`.

**Question 2: Is it possible to have 1 Disruptor with 2 producers, where each producer feeds a different dependency sub-graph?**

**Question 3: If the answer to Question 2 is no, is it possible to share a consumer, `Cx`, between two different disruptors, and If so, how?**

**Question 4: If the answer to both Question 2 & Question 3 is no, is there any way to make this topology work with the Disruptor?**

Thanks in advance!

**-- For reference --**

This is not a solution, but related. For anyone interested, [this blog](http://www.symphonious.net/2011/07/11/lmax-disruptor-high-performance-low-latency-and-simple-too/) explains how to create a semi-complex workflow, e.g., like this:

> ```
>         C1a --> C1b
>         C2a --> C2b  
>  P1 --> C3a --> C3b --> Cx
>         C4a --> C4b
>         C5a --> C5b
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I believe the `WorkerPool` will do that. Essentially as each worker becomes free it grabs the next work item. As you say, the won't necessarily complete in order. However, I've never used the `WorkerPool` in anger, so I could be wrong on that.

For your second question, if you conceptually replaced `Cx` with another disruptor (ring buffer) and hung `Cx` off the back of that, would that meet your other requirements? That is, have the work done by `C1[a-e]` be published to another disruptor, and have the work done by `C2b` published to the same disruptor.

Comment: thanks @dty, regarding the second question, yeah the `Cx` part is actually already implemented as another disruptor, though the first part has not yet been made into disruptors (good ole' fashioned queues and executors still) - haven't had time

Comment: for the record, what you're saying is to have 1 disruptor for every producer, right? and then an additional one also, for `Cx`